# Python: How to remove duplicate/similar lines

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, duplicates, similarity

I have one file with lots of messages. Each line a unique message that will be structured similar to each other with a slight modification. An example would be as follow:

```
Error number 609 at line 10
Error number 609 at line 22
Error string "foo" at line 11
Error string "bar" at line 14
```

and would like the output to be something like:

```
Error number 609 at line 10
Error string "foo" at line 11
```

They're the "same" type of error.

I managed to remove similar lines but the problem I'm having is how many times would I have to loop through each line in a file till it has no more "duplicates".

What I currently have:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

lst = open("result.txt").readlines()
print(len(lst))
for i in lst:
    for index, line in enumerate(lst):
        try:
            if similar(lst[index],lst[index + 1]) > 0.8:
                lst.pop(index)
        except:
            pass

print(len(lst))
```

But this isn't a sure method because it could be an overkill of times looped or it might not be enough if the file is really large with many of the "same" lines.

EDIT:

A more accurate example of one of many types of messages in a file would be something along the lines of:

```
[{TYPE}] Timeout after {miliseconds} millis, source ref: {random-number}, system: {system}, delivered {system}: , current {system}: {time}
```

Comment: Look for the difference with `Error number` and `Error string`?

Comment: You want to remove all duplicates of the same type?

Comment: @DirtyBit these are just small example messages that aren't really in the file. The lines will be a lot longer and more complicated.

Comment: @InyoungKim Yes. so in the end I know the "types" of messages in each line without worrying about the slight difference between them

Comment: Is the text file format fixed to: "Error(space)type(space)at line(space)value"

Comment: @MarcoFernandes I think I get the "it might be overkill" but not "it might be not enough". Could you explain in what case you are not getting lines "regrouped" enough ?

Comment: @InyoungKim I have edited the question to show an example of just one type of error message. I don't know all because it would have hundreds over a 6 year period that's been collected but not tracked or documented.

Comment: There are some small adjustments you could make to improve the performance. You can try to group the messages so you don't compare completly different messages. For example you could group them by the number of tokes the line has, or group them by the error number or even by length of the line with some allowance. That way you don't have an exponential algorithm. If the location of the line doesn't matter you could sort it and do a single pass through?

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek this file has 6 years of messages that has never been sorted or tracked/documented. I want to get all possible error types since I do not have access to source code to figure it out.

Comment: Not sure of the definition _similar_ here. Similarity can be defined in multiple ways. Are you defining similarities based on the 0,1,3,4th word of each line?

Comment: @Chris in the EDIT section of my question I added one message example type that I'd like to group, what's in the curly brackets would be different and I don't care for what would be in the curly bracket(these brackets don't exist in the actual message, they're place holders here) but the file has hundreds of completely different ones and I just want to get a collection of all possible types. without manually having to go through thousands of lines.

Comment: You could also try cat file.log | sort | uniq  and use it as input for your program or even use uniq -w to get similar lines

Comment: @MarcoFernandes I happen to have a quick script that can install from pip. Source code is [here](https://github.com/arthur-hav/levmatch). It's a log parser that regroup similar lines. Try `pip install levmatch` (you might need python-dev or python3-dev) and see what the command `levmatch` can do for your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each entry in input file is in the following format...

> ```
> [{TYPE}] Timeout after {miliseconds} millis, source ref: {random-number}...
> ```

```
lst = open("result.txt").readlines()

pretoken = "["
posttoken = "]"

foundTypes = []
log = []

for line in lst:
    foundType = ""
    for letter in line:
        if letter == pretoken: pass
        elif letter == posttoken: break
        else: foundType += letter

    if foundType not in foundTypes:
        foundTypes.append(foundType)
        log.append(line)

print(log)
```

Comment: This one helped a lot with that one error but the others are still very unique compered to the one example I gave. But thank you. this cut my file down from 24000 lines to 300 at least.

Answer (score 1):

You just need line by line open and read log file.

```
a=b=None
with open('result.txt') as infile:
    if a == None:
        a = infile.readline()
    b = infile.readline()
    while a:
        a = infile.readline()
        print('proc similar(a,b)')
        b = a
```

Comment: Thank you. this helped a bit but not to the extent I needed but it gave me something to work with and edit a bit to do what I need.